# 404 error - paths not working in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I recently used the CLI to create a new Angular project and then added my own HTML. Everything worked well, except that I realized that the project Angular2, not Angular 4. After some investigating, I realized that I was running on an earlier version of NodeJS and a beta version of the CLI. So I uninstalled everything and installed the latest versions. I then moved my current project to a new folder (as backup) and then started again clean, creating a new project with the CLI. Yay, this time it created an Angular4 project. So far so good.

Then I copied back my index.html and /src/ folders and tried to run it.

Now, every single reference to any file from index.html (e.g. /css/mystyle.css, /img/myimage.jpg) gives me a 404 error. But the files are definitely there.

Why is my index.html giving me 404 errors on existing files simply from switching from Ang2 to Ang4?

Comment: you do have inside `assets/` dir, right? And in the URLs there's `assets/` prefix? or you have it in your `src/` dir?

Comment: I see there is an assets folder under /src. But no, I have nothing under /assets, so for example, my /js and /css folders are in the root under /src, the same level as /assets and index.html. This worked as expected in Ang2. Does Ang4 look for thing in the /assets folder? If, for example, I moved my /css folder to /src/assets/css, then what is the path from index.html?

Comment: If you move css folder under assets, the path will be `/assets/css/....` . When you will build the code, the dist folder will contain assets folder.

Comment: Santosh, this worked as advertised, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that cli has default `assets` folder configured to output that as a static content as per `.angular-cli.json` config:

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

So if you have any other static content besides `asset` folder that just won't be outputed by default unless you configure that yourself. However in your case sound like you just have to copy your static files under `assets` to fix your problem. You can run `ng build` to play with `assets` option, this way you will see what is gets outputed and what is not.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this. Can you tell me where this info came from? Ang4 seems to be a different animal than Ang2 and I'm learning more from trial and error than from what I can find in walkthru's and docs.

Comment: @ToddDavis the info coming mostly from the experience :) but there is some docs you might find useful https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories

Comment: Thank you so much. Moving the folders under the /assets folder fixed pretty much everything. I'm also learning about the angular-cli.json which is good info to know.